# обрезать строку до определенного слова

Tags: bash

Есть строка start_string_end. Как получить в переменную все, что до "string", то есть "start_" и в другую переменную то, что после "string", то есть "_end"?

Comment: `$ s="start_string_end"; echo ${s%string*}; echo ${s#*string}`

Answer (score 2):

Добавляю как общий ответ.

Самый простой и быстрый вариант:

```
 s="start_string_end"
 var1=${s%string*} #До стринг
 var2=${s#*string} #После стринг
```

вариант: [Aleksandr Barakin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/aleksandr-barakin)

---

Вариант если передача идет в потоке, без предварительного объявления переменной:

```
 var1=`echo "start_string_end" | awk -F 'string' '{print $1}'`
 var2=`echo "start_string_end" | awk -F 'string' '{print $2}'`
```

либо

```
 var1=`echo "start_string_end" | sed 's/string.*//g`
 var2=`echo "start_string_end" | sed 's/.*string//g`
```

`echo` написан для примера, как stdout от какой-либо программы.